# Redisson and Spring Boot to connect to the AWS EC2 Hosting Redis

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, redis, redisson

Hi I have installed Redis on AWS-EC2 instance. I am able to ping the instance from my local machine.

I have opened all ports on my EC2 instance so i should be able to connect and ping the Redis Server.

I am able to ping the EC2 server using the IP(public)

I want to hit the Redis server from my Windows local machine  running Spring boot application(with Redission)

In my spring boot I have configured the file(Json) with  Single Server Configurations. This is as described in the link below -
https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration

```
{    
   "singleServerConfig":{

      "idleConnectionTimeout":10000,
      "connectTimeout":10000,
      "timeout":3000,
      "retryAttempts":3,
      "retryInterval":1500,
      "password":null,
      "subscriptionsPerConnection":5,
      "clientName":null,
      "address": "redis://<EC2-IP>:6379",
      "subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize":1,
      "subscriptionConnectionPoolSize":50,
      "connectionMinimumIdleSize":24,
      "connectionPoolSize":64,
      "database":0,
      "dnsMonitoringInterval":5000    
    },    
   "threads":16,    
   "nettyThreads":32,    
   "codec":{
      "class":"org.redisson.codec.FstCodec"    
    },    
    "transportMode":"NIO" 
}
```

Then i am instantiating bean in my spring boot app-

```
@Bean(name="redissonClient",destroyMethod="shutdown")   public
RedissonClient redissonClient() { return Redisson.create(config); }
```

However, i am getting an exception below -

```
2019-11-18 14:54:54.432  WARN 81628 --- [isson-netty-1-6] io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline  : An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: CommandDecoder.decode() must consume the inbound data or change its state if it did not decode anything.
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:379) ~[netty-codec-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.channelInputClosed(ReplayingDecoder.java:329) ~[netty-codec-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:359) ~[netty-codec-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342) ~[netty-codec-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245) [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224) [netty-transport-4.1.27.Final.jar:4.1.27.Final
```

The link below points that this is fixed - https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/1566
and occurs when we can not communicate to the redis server.

As I have all ports opened on EC2 i don't think communication should be a problem for redis on port 6379. Still i am facing the issue. please help if any one has any idea or if i am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: you can install redis on ec2 and then try to connect local host application hosted on your PC/Laptop using Public IP of Ec2

Comment: Unable to reproduce this. Could you provide any code example? Which Redisson version do you use?